# How to change the text of button three times in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Hi Friends here i have done the code for change text of button, like if i press the button the text of the button will change. But i need the text of the button to be change one more time,
eg: initially "Button1" -->(click)-->"Button2" -->(click)-->"Button3".

I need button3 also.

please reffer:http://jsfiddle.net/Ljrpd/17/

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

})

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
$scope.toggle = true;

$scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
    $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Button1' : 'Button2';
})
})
```

Some one help me out in this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need **toggle** variable, you can store selected index as suggested by Peter. I would also add check for last selection:

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.buttonIndex = 0;
    $scope.buttonNames = ['Button 1', 'Button 2', 'Button 3', 'Last Button']
    $scope.changeText = function() {
        if ($scope.buttonIndex === $scope.buttonNames.length - 1) {
            $scope.buttonIndex = 0;
        } else {
            $scope.buttonIndex += 1;
        }
    };
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljrpd/21/)

Answer (score 0):

Try my modification:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljrpd/18/

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{buttonNames[buttonIndex]}}</button>


var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

})

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = true;
    $scope.buttonIndex = 0;
    $scope.buttonNames = ['first', 'second', 'third']

    $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
        $scope.buttonIndex += 1;
    })
})
```

And here's a version without a watch:

http://jsfiddle.net/russf6s9/1/

```
<button ng-click="incrementButton()">{{buttonNames[buttonIndex]}}</button>


var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

})

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.buttonIndex = 0;
    $scope.incrementButton = function() {
        $scope.buttonIndex += 1;
    }
    $scope.buttonNames = ['first', 'second', 'third']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive:

```
app.directive('changeText', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      changeText: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.index = 0;
      element.html(scope.changeText[0]);

      element.on('click', function(){
        scope.index = (scope.index + 1) % scope.changeText.length; 
        element.html(scope.changeText[scope.index]);
      })
    }
  };
})
```

Then in your html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <button change-text="ctrl.textValues"></button>
</body>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.btntext='button_1';
                $scope.changetext = function () {
                $scope.btntext = ($scope.btntext=='button_1')?'button_2':($scope.btntext=='button_2')?'button_3':'button_1';
                }
});
```

Markup:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="changetext()" ng-value="btntext"/>
```

[View in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SsgOow0SD97WVyKPExaU)